# Get a list of enabled and not locked-out Active Directory Users in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have below cmdlet:

```
  get-aduser -filter {Enabled -eq 'true' -and LockedOut -eq 'true'} -Properties samaccountname, givenname, sn, physicalDeliveryOfficeName | 
             Select-Object -Property samaccountname, givenname, sn, physicalDeliveryOfficeName |
             Export-Csv -Encoding Default -path $csvOutputPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Now I need to add a filter to exclude locked-out AD users in the above get-aduser cmdlet.... but I do not know how to do it....

I know I can obtain locked-out users using below:

Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly -Locked

So any idea?

Comment: Wouldn't you want the filter of `LockedOut -eq 'false'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to keep this within one query, you could filter against the UserAccountControl property. Documentation shows that a locked out account has the 0x0010 (hex) or 16 (decimal base 10) bit flagged. Therefore, you should be able to use the bitwise AND operator (-band) to determine the lockout status.

```
get-aduser -filter {Enabled -eq 'true' -and (-not (UserAccountControl -band 16))} -Properties samaccountname, givenname, sn, physicalDeliveryOfficeName | 
             Select-Object -Property samaccountname, givenname, sn, physicalDeliveryOfficeName |
             Export-Csv -Encoding Default -path $csvOutputPath -NoTypeInformation
```

The `-not` operator is used for accounts that are not locked out. You can remove it if you want to find locked out accounts.

You could technically use `UserAccountControl` for your entire filter, but it isn't as human readable. Here is an example of how the `-band` operator works here:

> ```
> # Enabled User not locked has useraccountcontrol = 512
> [bool](512 -band 16)
> False
>
> # Enabled User locked has useraccountcontrol = 528
> PS C:\temp\test1> [bool](528 -band 16)
> True
>
> # Locked Enabled User with expired password
> [bool](8389136 -band 16)
> True
> ```

See [UserAccountControl Flags](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/305144/how-to-use-useraccountcontrol-to-manipulate-user-account-properties) for more information on the bits used for determining UserAccountControl values.

See [About_Arithmetic_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-6) for more information on bitwise operators.